# Unescape Characters for DBeaver

Tags: java, sql, database, escaping, dbeaver

Previously, when I migrated SQL queries from JAVA to DBeaver, SQL queries were automatically escaped to the correct format.
I am currently working on Mac OS and the escaping feature is not working.
How can I turn it on?

The current version of DBeaver is 23.2.1.20209260508

For example, I copy an sql query from JAVA -

```
"SELECT pal.cod \"SC\" FROM " + (String)env + ".gerece"
```

I want this sql query to be automatically escaped to the correct format -

```
SELECT pal.cod "SC" FROM env.gerece
```

Does anyone know how to enable this feature? I asked ChatGPT, but it gives incorrect answers

Comment: can you not use single quotes with SC

Comment: I don't choose which quotes to use. I need to perform automatic request escaping when copying requests from JAVA projects to DBeaver. It was - "\"Hello\"", it should be - "Hello"

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> Code Editor, go to Auto Format and check "Extract SQL from source code." I ran into this today.